# Getting error while creating CListCtrl

Tags: image, visual-c++, mfc, clistctrl

I'm trying to create a CListCtrl in MFC. 
I am getting while making CImageList.

```
BOOL CRadioButtonTestDlg::InitImageList() {
    mImageListNormal.Create(32, 32, ILC_COLOR32, 39, 1);
    CString filePath;
    CFileFind finder;
    CString strWildcard(_T("E:\\MyAssignments\\Window system programming\\MFC\\sample_programs\\VContact\\res\\contact_images\\*.jpg"));
    BOOL bWorking = finder.FindFile(strWildcard);
    while (bWorking) {
        bWorking = finder.FindNextFile();
        if (finder.IsDots())
            continue;
        filePath = finder.GetFilePath();
        CImage image;
        CBitmap bitmap;
        image.Load(filePath);
        bitmap.Attach(image.Detach());
        mImageListNormal.Add(&bitmap, RGB(255, 0, 255));
        bitmap.DeleteObject();
    }
    finder.Close();

    if(mAllContactListCtrl.SetImageList(&mImageListNormal, LVSIL_NORMAL) == NULL)
        AfxMessageBox(_T("Falied to set ImageList"));

    return TRUE;
}
```

call to mAllContactListCtrl.SetImageList() failed.

I want know whether using creating CBitmap from CImage is correct or I'm doing wrong some where else.

In the output I'm just getting string but not the Image.

=========================================================================

I am calling the above function from InitDialog()

```
BOOL CRadioButtonTestDlg::OnInitDialog() {
    CDialog::OnInitDialog();

    CRect rect;
    mAllContactListCtrl.GetClientRect(&rect);
    mAllContactListCtrl.InsertColumn(0, _T("Name"), LVCFMT_LEFT, rect.Width()-15, 0);
    for (int i = 0; i < 39; i++) {
        mAllContactListCtrl.InsertItem(i, _T("Some String"), i);
    }
    InitImageList();

    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting? From where are you calling `InitImageList()`. Does the `mAllContactListCtrl` window exist yet at that point - ie. Are you doing this before the dialog is invoked (wrong) or after/during `OnInitDialog()` (correct).

Comment: `LVSIL_NORMAL` sets the image list for large icons. Maybe your list control is running in small-icon mode?

Comment: I am using image of size 32*32.

Comment: thanks  Frédéric Hamidi

Yes changing to LVSIL_SMALL fixes the problem. thanks alot!